# How to differentiate between videos and images when getting from gallery into a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gallery

I want to get images and videos from phone gallery and display in a recyclerveiw. In recyclerview adapter, I've two viewtypes, one for displaying images and second for displaying videos. But I don't know how to set a check between videos and images to differentiate between two viewtypes.

This how I'm getting images from gallery, and its working fine. But what if I also get videos just like this and want to set those in other viewtype, just say videoview.

```
//method to get the list of images from gallery
private ArrayList<String> getAllShownImagesPath(Activity activity) {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
    ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    String absolutePathOfImage = null;
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};


    cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    column_index_folder_name = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
    }
    return listOfAllImages;
}
```

Please guide me how to get all videos and images from gallery with a single cursor or method and display those in different viewtypes in recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the MIME Type of a media retrieved from Gallery in your recyclerview.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap , refer this official documentation. This is the clear solution as dealing with media files. Give it a try.

Comment: There is not much in documentation about the use of MIME. Please be more specific with your answer. At least, show me how to use MIME Type in my use case.

Comment: You can go with this so you can get MIMETYPE of media file. And separate Images & Videos
`// url = file path or whatever suitable URL you want.

public static String getMimeType(String url) {
String type = null;
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
if (extension != null) {
type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
}
return type;
}`